# Can't build LLVM examples | unknown component name: jit

Tags: llvm

I have built LLVM & Clang according to the docs [here](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html).

The steps were

- `export SRC_DIR=/work/llvm`
- `export BUILD_DIR=/work/make_llvm`
- `cd $BUILD_DIR`
- `$SRC_DIR/configure --prefix=/work/my_llvm`
- `make -j 4`
- `make install`

My `PATH` does have `/work/my_llvm/bin` at the front.

Then I `cd $BUILD_DIR/examples` and type `make` to which the system responds,

```
llvm-config: unknown component name: jit
make[1]: Entering directory `/work/make_llvm/examples/BrainF'
/work/llvm/Makefile.rules:1071: *** llvm-config --libs failed.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/work/make_llvm/examples/BrainF'
make: *** [BrainF/.makeall] Error 2
```

Seems like there's not JIT support, or `llvm-config` can't find it. But LLVM compiles with JIT support enabled by default according `configure --help`, and I see at least one JIT related library called `libLLVMMCJIT.a` in `/work/my_llvm/lib`.

How do I build the LLVM examples?

Answer (score 6):

The legacy JIT component has been removed from upstream LLVM just this week (and all its uses switched to MCJIT). I recall seeing reports of problems with the examples on the mailing list, but they were fixed. Is this a fresh check-out of LLVM or an older one? If it's a fresh check-out, you should send a note to llvmdev@ or open a bug about it, because it would mean this example was left behind.